# Handling panic and deferred func

Tags: go

First of all I love GO :D I have some questions about panic/recover. Panic can be recovered only in deferred funcs? Is deferred func called when deadlock happens? I have tested it and no... Can you please explain why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Panic can be recovered only in deferred funcs?

Yes, only in deferred funcs.

> Is deferred func called when deadlock happens? I have tested it and no... Can you please explain why not?

It is an implementation choice made by the authors of the Go run-time. The assumption is that recovering from a deadlock is practically impossible.

Comment: Whether or not defers run on deadlock is not an implementation choice. If you have a deadlock, then some functions aren't returning so defers will not run on those goroutines. The exception, where you're correct, is a deadlock in which no goroutine can run. That triggers a panic but does not run deferred functions.

Comment: @EvanShaw (1)I meant that when the run-time detects a full (program-wide) deadlock it would start running the deferred functions, and if a deferred function calls recover() then the run-time would reschedule the goroutine for normal execution. Implementing this feature in the run-time seems possible and it wouldn't be hard to implement - which is why I wrote that it is an implementation choice. (2)I think that a partial deadlock, as you seem to be suggesting in your 2nd sentence, is more problematic than a full deadlock. In either case, recovery from a deadlock is a weird and circular idea.